# django two 'static' path in my url?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

My static file setting is

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
```

and i install ckeditor in my project, and in urls.py :

```
url(r'static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,}),
(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
```

when i get ckeditor.js from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/chicinfo/article/add/static/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`, I can't get this file.
Below picture show my problem:
[image]

What happen to me?

Comment: Could you please let us know you template code where you include static content and please update STATIC_URL = 'static/' to STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: If any of the below answers resolved your problem, please mark one of them as correct.

Comment: @AnshJ I tried to modify that to '/static/ but i found that all css files in admin main page is missing. when i use 'static/', css files in admin is fine.
Which one should i choose?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are putting /static/ in the actual url in your templates. E.g,

```
<scirpt src="{{ STATIC_URL }}static/ckeditor/ckeditor/jkeditor.js" />
```

You don't need to put the static bit in if you are using static_url. It should be:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}ckeditor/ckeditor/jkeditor.js" />
```

You should also put the static files serving URL at the end of your url config.

Working example:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
    'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, }),
```

Comment: I didn't modify the source of ckeditor.js because it's a app. And it will parse url by this application itself. by just add `(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),`